# Реализация печати с помощью DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

Необходимо сделать в программе функцию печати. Посоветовали DevExpress. Загрузил и установил. Что дальше? Как подключить и как осуществить печать? Буду рад советам и полезным ссылкам.

Answer (score 3):

Интересует печать именно через компоненты DevExpress'a? Или просто не знаете как? Ведь в .NET Framework есть класс PrintDocument, позволяющий напечатать всё, что угодно. В MSDN есть [пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx).

Если нужно именно DevExpress, в понедельник могу спросить на работе у тех кто с ним работал.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, посмотрю обязательно. Я действительно не знаю как сделать печать, вот посоветовали через devexpress. Тогда уж попробую через PrintDocument, но было бы неплохо и через devexpress попробовать сделать.

Comment: в понедельник тогда узнаю напишу

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужна XtraPrinting Library.
Ссылка на описание основных возможностей этой библиотеки: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2080

Также не забудьте, что если вы скачали триал версию с официального сайта DevExpress, то вы можете бесплатно месяц пользоваться их саппортом, который сможет помочь вам распечатать что и как угодно =)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы в DevExpress хотите распечатать отчет, то создаете отчет `DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport`, затем из другого класса отправляете его на печать:

```
     Reports.YourReportName rep = new Reports.YourReportName();
     ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(rep);
     printTool.Print();
```